# On string with white space, python command .isspace() gives result false

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to split the string with white space got from `xpath` but it didn't work

```
 x="78646182309549（5）" 
 x.split()
```

so I checked if there is white space on the string using

```
x.isspace()
```

it returns `False`

Html:

```
<td class="tl"><a href="https://www.zto.com/?num=78646182309549（5）" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">78646182309549（5）</a></td>


 x = response.xpath("(//td[@class='tl']//a)[1]/text()").extract_first()
 print(x)
 print(x.isspace())
```

Desired output:

```
x = ['78646182309549','(5)']
y = x[0]
print(y)
78646182309549
```

Comment: What's the question/ desired output?

Comment: isspace checks if the string is space. It does not validate whether text contains space

Comment: @MendelG I have updated the question check it agan for desired output

Answer (score 1):

*The isspace() method returns True if all the characters in a string are whitespaces, otherwise False.*

Technically there are no spaces in x:

```
[y for y in x]

['7', '8', '6', '4', '6', '1', '8', '2', '3', '0', '9', '5', '4', '9', '（', '5', '）']
```

This :

```
"78646182309549（5）".split()
```

returns :

```
['78646182309549（5）']
```

You can split with this:

```
x="78646182309549（5）".split('（')
#output ['78646182309549', '5）']
x[0]='78646182309549'
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/dIQGstWrFrVB What is this then??

Answer (score 1):

`isspace()` returns `True` if the all string is a space

```
'   '.isspace() # True
```

and to split by space you need to use

```
split(' ')
```

But this won't help here since `（` is a single character in your text. You separate this text using `re.split`

```
x = "78646182309549（5）"
x = re.split(r'(（)', x)
x1, x2 = x[0], ''.join(x[1:])
# or
x = [x[0], ''.join(x[1:])]

print(x[0]) # 78646182309549
print(x[1]) # （5）
```

Edit

As suggested by @mozway you can do

```
x = "78646182309549（5）"
x = re.split(r'(?=（)', x)
print(x) # ['78646182309549', '（5）']
```

Comment: With `re.split(r'(?=（)', x)` you won't need to `join`